Feynman diagram problem with two complex scalar fields
I have a problem about interaction between two scalar complex fields:
Consider a theory with complex scalar fields $\phi$ (charge 1, mass $m$) and $\chi$ (charge 2, mass $M$) with lagrangian $\mathcal{L} =\mathcal{L}_{free}+\mathcal{L}_{int}$, where
$$\mathcal{L}_{free} = \partial_{\mu}\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi + \partial_{\mu}\chi^*\partial^{\mu}\chi+m^2|\phi|^2 + M^2|\chi|^2$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{int} = -\dfrac{\lambda}{4}|\phi|^4 - \dfrac{\lambda'}{4}|\chi|^4 - \lambda''|\phi|^2|\chi|^2-\left( \dfrac{\mu}{2}\phi^2\chi^*+h.c \right)$$
where the coupling constants $\lambda, \lambda', \lambda''$ are real numbers and $\mu$ is complex.
1 . Find the tree-level scattering amplitudes for the processes:
a) $\phi^+ + \phi^+ \to \phi^+ + \phi^+$
b) $\phi^+ + \phi^- \to \chi^+ + \chi^-$
c) $\chi^+ + \chi^+ \to  4\phi^+$
where $\phi^+$ and $\chi^+$ are particles and $\phi^-$ and $\chi^-$ are antiparticles. Using Feynman diagrams describe explicitly the  flow of charge and moment, considering conservation of momentum at each vertex.

Looks like a homework problem. If you have a specific aspect of this problem that you need to understand to solve it, then you can focus your question here on that specific aspect.

It's something like that, it's a problem that was pending in a QFT class, but I have difficulties understanding how to solve it, that is, I want to understand how the Feynman diagrams are developed for this case, and I would greatly appreciate the support.
